# Loading objects created by specific user in python/Django

Tags: python, django

So in my views.py I have a tools list which is a list of all tools from within the database.
I want to somehow filter through this list to only load tools created by the current user.

the tool's owner is a ShedUser object, who's name can be accessed by tool.owner.user.username,
and I've tried referencing the user by things like user.username in the html document. As you can see in my html template code

```
{% if tool.owner.user.username == user.username %}
```

in the html in attempt to filter through the total list.
I have had no success in filtering the total list in the python file or html template. I've also tried different ways of only generating a list of tools created by the user in the first place, but can't find a way to do that either.

Here are my files

my root/tool/views.py:

```
http://pastebin.com/ri93S7Gq
```

my root/site/templates/shelf.html:

```
http://pastebin.com/Qmrirk2y
```

my root/tool/models.py:

```
http://pastebin.com/v6nS6L4B
```

my root/user/models.py:

```
http://pastebin.com/pNqkNVCG
```

Comment: Show us more details (template, view maybe?)

Comment: Please post your view and model code.

Comment: sorry, I'm confused as to what files you want? I have the views, both models, and template listed there

Comment: we want views, models and templates

Comment: -1 for linking to code on pastebin rather than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter the results before rendering them.

In the view you'll need to do something like:

```
tools = Tool.objects.filter(owner__user=request.user).order_by('name')
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, exactly as you stated it! Thank you so much